# Change width and height using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple sentence trying to get select input like:

```
$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").attr("style","height:30px;" "width:100px");
```

But I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

Strange think is if I only use one style like:

```
$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").attr("style","height:30px;");
```

it works, so how can I add height and width in same attr? Regards

Comment: Better to do $("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").addClass('whatever');

Comment: It is one of those long epiphany things, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").attr("style","height:30px;width:100px");
// "height:30px;width:100px" not "height:30px;" "width:100px"
```

However, changing the `style` attribute will discard previous inline-styles that were set in the original markup, to prevent this you can use jQuery's `.css()` function, which will add a new style property if it isn't set and override it if it is:

```
$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").css({
    'height':'30px',
    'width':'100px'
});
```

For multiple selects with multiple titles use this:

```
var titles="Tipo de solicitud,Valor de Estatus";

$.each(titles.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("select[title='" + e + "']").css({
        'height':'30px',
        'width':'100px'
    });
});
```

Comment: one question, if I have more than one select that I want to apply same css, is it possible to add multiple titles too?

Comment: @Ledwing Yes you can, just separate them with a comma `, ` like you do in css.

Comment: I try to do as `$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud,Valor de Estatus']").css({
   'height':'30px',
    'width':'800px'
});` separatted with coma but it no works

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select[title='Tipo de solicitud']").css({"height":"30px","width":"100px"});
```